# Is Kotlin eval() dangerous?

Tags: javascript, kotlin, eval

I read [in the documentation of Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!):

> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension.

My question is: it is same thing in Kotlin? If so, why it was implemented, considering Kotlin a more advanced and modern language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Kotlin for JavaScript projects the Kotlin code will be transpiled to JavaScript code. To provide full compatibility also `eval()` is available. And to answer the main question:

**Yes, `eval()` used in Kotlin code is as dangerous as using it in JavaScript code** and should be avoided for the same reasons you already mentioned in your question.

When using Kotlin for a JVM based Project or Native Project, you don't have access to the eval-function, because it is only compatible with JavaScript.